# ffmpeg on android: playing MPEG2 TS udp multicast stream

Tags: android, networking, stream, ffmpeg, playback

I want to make android media player using ffmpeg. 
(catch MPEG2 TS multicast stream via WIFI network and decode it)
I checked followings:

- My iptime AP supports WIFI multicast protocol.
  (send multicast stream in wired PC, and wifi connected PC can receive it)
- My Android phone can receive multicast stream via WIFI.
  I coded NDK socket programming which is join udp multicast group and receive packets
  (I added multicast access grant to AndroidManifest.xml)
- FFMPEG library is ported to android and it can play local media file.

But when I try to open network stream using FFMPEG library, avformat_open_input() function returns fail.

```
gFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
av_register_all(); 
avcodec_register_all(); 
avformat_network_init(); 
if(avformat_open_input(&gFormatCtx,"udp://@239.100.100.100:4000",NULL,NULL) != 0)
    return -2;
```

this code always return "-2". 
If I use "av_dict_set()" api, which option should I use?

```
av_dict_set(&options, "udp_multicast", "mpegtsraw", 0);
```

please let me know what should I check for avformat_open_input error?

thanks.

Comment: What value is returned by `avformat_open_input`? Does your code work on a Desktop? If you haven't tried I would suggest to do it on Desktop first (a standalone application to test you C code) because it is easier to debug. Use the same ffmpeg version and go debug mode (or at least display all values returned by the API).

Comment: what a stupid.. there was a "--disable-network" in configure option. :(  After change it to "--enable-network", avformat_open_input() return success.

Comment: @user1513822 i am also facing the same problem. But after changing the enable-network option also i cannot be able to play the rtp stream. Please help me in this.